# Apache storm - how to disable bolt from configuration

Tags: java, apache-storm

I need to disable some bolt from [Config](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/javadocs/org/apache/storm/Config.html) or use another way without code modification.

Adding "topology.*bolt_name*.enabled = false" doesn't help

My Storm version is 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you want to edit topology layout without recompiling code, take a look at Flux https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/flux.html. If you write your topology using that DSL, you can remove/add bolts as you like without recompiling.